# Find the root of the equation

Tags: calculus, optimization

$1.2t^2 + 24 - 2.4t(t+4)ln(0.25t+1) = 0$

The original equation was $M = (1.2 ln(0.25t+1))/(t^2+20)$, and I've derived and simplified it until I arrived at the first equation to attempt to find the max. It should be about 3.44503, but I can't seem to figure out the steps to get there (Wolfram Alpha hasn't had the option to show steps).

Comment: but the original equation is different from yours

Comment: $$M=\frac{1.2\ln(0.25t+1)}{t^2+20}$$

Comment: Keep in mind that for most equations are simply not solvable in 'steps', that is in closed form simply by algebraic manipulation. Unless there's some clever trick hidden in the equation, you'll have to resort to numerical methods to find the solutions.

Comment: Plus, what happened to the M in the original equation?

Comment: I derived the original equation, then simplified the derivation until I got the first equation. I'm trying to optimize the second equation, but I thought it'd be easier to give you something half-way done than at the start. The second equation is there just in case someone wants to start from there instead if they don't trust my work (and they probably shouldn't). M is the total mass of fish and t is time in months.

Comment: @Nick : You made a fundamuntal mistake : The solution of an equation is not equal to the solution of the derived equation. For example, with equation $x^2=4$ the solutions are $x=\pm2$. If you derive the equation you obtain $2x=0$ which solution is $x=0$

Comment: I'm attempting to find the value for t which gives M the largest value. From what I know, I can derive the equation and equate it to 0 to get the value for t.

Comment: You just have to use numerical method to get that value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve it only with numerical calculus.

An easy method : First draw the curve of equation $M(t)$ and pick on the curve the usefull points. This gives an approximate of the wanted result.

Second, if more accuracy is requiered, use a numerical method (Newton-Raphson for example).

If the goal corresponds to the maximum of $M$, then the result is : $M\simeq 0.02339329$ and $t\simeq 3.44503258$

[image]